# Creating an input stream object in Hadoop for reading a file

Tags: java, hadoop, bigdata

I have a file in my Hadoop filesystem and I need to create an InputStream object in-order to pass it as an input parameter to another API as `ApiMethod(inputstreamObject)`.

I am using below approach as mentioned in Definitive Guide to create an input stream object but does not work.

```
class test {

        static {    
        URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(new FsUrlStreamHandlerFactory());  } 

        InputStream in = null; 
        try {  
        in = new URL("hdfs://host/path").openStream();  
        IOUtils.copyBytes(in, System.out, 4096, false);
        Object = new ApiMethod(in);
        } finally {  
        IOUtils.closeStream(in); } 

}
```

Please help.

Comment: Firstly, Do you want to read a file in Hadoop through Java API..?? Secondly, are you facing any issue while using this method.

Comment: @salmanbw Thank you for replying. Yes. My intention is to create an Inputstream object of the file and pass it to the method like "ApiMethod(in)" . This method is a 3rd party Java API which will take care of reading it internally. When I try creating object using above mentioned code, I get this exception " Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused".

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to read a file from hadoop,let's try this approach.
Read a file from hadoop and write it to a local path or print it on screen.

```
FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(conf);

Path path = new Path("/path/to/file");

FSDataInputStream in = fileSystem.open(path);
OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
    new File(fileOnLocal)));

byte[] b = new byte[1024];
int numBytes = 0;
while ((numBytes = in.read(b)) > 0) {
    out.write(b, 0, numBytes);
}

in.close();
out.close();
fileSystem.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I specifically need to create an InputStream object for the file I am going to read.

Comment: Have you tried passing in as a parameter to that object.